# How to get MacPorts to install something without updating all existing packages

Tags: macports

I want to install something with MacPorts. However, I have a port installed (let's call it `badport`) that consistently fails to update. Every time I do `port install x-package` it tries to update *everything* before installing `x-package`. It inevitably fails to do anything with `x-package` because it's all hung up about `badport`, even though `badport` cannot possibly be a dependency (it's an application, not a library or even a command-line tool).

Further, for some reason, MacPorts tries to run *all* of these updates *every* time I run the command, as though the number of updates that ran successfully were rolled back solely because this end application failed to update.

Is there any way that I can tell MacPorts to stop trying to be "helpful" and just install my damn packages?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem? Maybe you can trick macports into believing your x-package already is up to date using the answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945589/how-do-i-ignore-unmark-certain-ports .

Comment: I haven't looked into this since I had the problem; for some reason it magically disappeared with what I was doing at the time.