# How do i ignore/unmark certain ports?

Tags: macports

I would like to know how to either ignore upgrading certain ports or unmark them as "outdated".

This is motivated by certain ports failing to upgrade, while I wish to upgrade all the rest. I know about `sudo port install -n`, which allows one to install a port without upgrading port dependencies, as in the case of `mongodb` requiring an older (not the current) version of the`boost` libraries, but this is not applicable here.

For example:

```
$ sudo port list outdated
gdb                            @7.5            devel/gdb
py27-scikits-image             @0.7.1          python/py-scikits-image
```

As `gdb@7.5` fails to update, I would just like to upgrade the others, ie. `py27-scikits-image`, without going thru the whole `sudo port list outdated | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v gdb | xargs sudo port upgrade` pipeline.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Not really a programming question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise to create a local portfile for gdb with a lower version number.

1. Create a local portfile repository: [howto](http://guide.macports.org/#development.local-repositories)
2. Copy the gdb portfile directory (a directory called "gdb" containing the file "Portfile" and directory "files") into your local portfile repository
3. Change the version number in the portfile to e.g. 0.0
4. Run `portindex` in your local portfile repository

The local portfile overrides the one downloaded from the default port repository. The low version number makes macports think your version of gdb is up to date.

I hope this can help.

BTW: you can do `sudo port upgrade outdated and not gdb`

Comment: thank you. is there a quick documentation i can consult for commands like the `and not gdb` suffix you suggested, and how portfiles/portindexes work in detail please?

Comment: The best place for information about portfiles and portindexes is http://guide.macports.org/ I think. The only documentation I found about the 'and' and 'not' operators was in the manpage of macports.

Comment: so there's no way to unmark a particular port as "outdated" or "inactive", but the portfile way that you've suggested?


Also, is there a way I can ask MacPorts to continue installing/upgrading the next port on encountering errors with a particular port, instead of terminating?

Comment: It's the only way I know of. You can try the -p option.

Comment: Just recently, I came across this use case (again!) trying to upgrade outdated ports. I would like to upgrade the list of outdated ports, except for a certain port X and all the other ports marked outdated which depend on X. `sudo port upgrade outdated and not X` doesn't quite work this way. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at rdepof:X. Maybe sudo port upgrade outdated and not rdepof:X will work.

Comment: If anyone is facing the problem described in the two comments above this one, have a look at the [comments here.](https://superuser.com/questions/1048053/how-can-i-exclude-a-port-from-macports-upgrade-outdated#comment1469126_1048053)